# How to retrieve tasks by section using asana api

Tags: api, asana

If a project contains multiple sections, how to retrieve tasks by section if we know the section name/id? Or is there any way to know which section a task belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a not-yet-fully-supported way to get the sections of a task - if you use `?opt_fields=projects.section.name` for instance, the response will contain the section task.

There is currently not a way to query for the tasks in a section.

Answer (score 0):

**2019 Update:** As of this Asana forum answer in Feb. 2018, you can now use:

```
https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/{projectID}/tasks?opt_fields=memberships.(project|section).name&opt_pretty
```